# sklearn StandardScaler returns all zeros for all input

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I am setting up input from the user in a matrix with 1 row and 8 column and the feature scale these value so that I can predict using the value in matrix the error which I get is

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2

I tried

```
  matrix = q.fit_transform(matrix[:, np.newaxis])
```

But it returns -Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.

```
 R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) 
 C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:")) 


 print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ") 

 entries = list(map(float, input().split())) 

 matrix = np.array(entries).reshape(R, C) 
 print(matrix)

 matrix = q.fit_transform(matrix)
```

I expect the `StandardScale` result but it returns

```
[0.000000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000000e+00     
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00     
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00     
0.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the logic of `StandardScaler`. Each datapoint is subtracted by mean and normalized with standard deviation. Hence, it becomes zeros if the number of datapoints is one.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> The standard score of a sample x is calculated as:
>
> z = (x - u) / s
>
> where u is the mean of the training samples or zero if
>   with_mean=False, and s is the standard deviation of the training
>   samples or one if with_std=False.

Hence, if you have only one data point, then the standard score is always going to be all zeros.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data = [[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
print(scaler.fit_transform(data))

# [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```